# xml validation using xsd in jaxb

Tags: xml-parsing

I have an xml.
I have created one XSD for the xml.

I want to write a prog to validate the xml against xsd.
I wrote a prog and got individual values am setting.

But is there a way, i can give the xml file as input and could see if the xml is valid against the XSD?

Thanks,
Nini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of xml validation with XSD.

```
public static boolean validate() {
    Source xmlFile = null;
    File schemaFile;
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory;
    Schema schema;
    try {
        schemaFile = new File(xsdFileName);
        xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File(xmlFileName));
        schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(xmlFile);
        System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
        System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could do using this concept.

Comment: But can u gv me one example using marshall/unmarshall?

Comment: @user468964 - You can set an instance of `Schema` on a `Marshaller` or `Unmarshaller` to enable validation.  For more information see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html